# set только для одного из перечислений

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно организовать одному из полей перечисления на запись/чтение, а остальным полям только на чтение?
Например есть класс:

```
public class Item
    {
        public enum StateList
        {
            OK,
            Error,
            Process,
            Completed
        }
private StateList _State = StateList.OK;
public StateList State
        {
            get { return _State; }
        }
    }
```

Вот чтобы для Completed было и на запись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем создал в классе Item метод

```
        public void Complete()
        {
            _State = StateList.Completed;
        }
```

Не знаю правильно или нет, придется таким способом менять состояние, не затрагивая другие поля перечисления.

Comment: Это наиболее правильное решение

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку проверить, какое именно значение передается в сеттер в `compile-time` нельзя, то единственный выход - *кинуть исключение типа `ArgumentException` во время выполнения.*

```
        public StateList State
        {
            get { return _State; }
            set
            {
                if (value != StateList.Completed) throw new ArgumentException(...);
                _State = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: каждый раз ловить исключения по производительности ударит наверно, но все равно спасибо за способ, буду знать

Answer (score 0):

Только метод вместо MorphState() лучше назвать Complete()

Comment: Сделано!         )